# Is this a normal behavior on .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm trying to get a nullable type from a nonnullable struct or class...

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(Guid?).ToString());
        Print<Guid>();
    }
    
    public static void Print<T>() where T : notnull
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T?).ToString());
    }
}
```

This code prints...

```
System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]
System.Guid
```

Is this normal?... typeof(T) or typeof(T?) returns the same in this code.

This code works fine with a "struct" constraint, but I need that works with strings too... Finally I solve with the code below, but I want to know if this is a bug or have some logic...

This code works for struct or classes like a string:

```
var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);

if (underlyingType == null) parameterType = typeof(TValue);
else parameterType = typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(underlyingType);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because `Guid` is a `struct` (not a `class`), it is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<Guid>` as a _Nullable value type_ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types). _Nullable reference types_ are a different language feature that also uses `?` which is used with reference types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types

Comment: Ah, ok, but... I don't know how net core determines what syntactic sugar I'm using, with struct constraint on the generic method, the same code works fine (only for structs, obviously). Without struct constraint, with Guid (or other struct) as T parameter, T?  it's the same type of T... I think it's a bit confusing. Thanks!